# Using References in SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to create two tables (Users,Messages).
The users table which consists of a primary key(RoomID) which I will reference to in my Messages tables. This is the query I am attempting to run.

```
String CREATE_TABLE_MESSAGES = "CREATE TABLE " + Messages.TABLE  + "( "
                + "FOREIGN KEY(" + Messages.KEY_ROOMID  + ") REFERENCES "+ChatRooms.TABLE+"("+ChatRooms.KEY_ROOMID+"), "
                + Messages.MESSAGE+ " TEXT, "
                + Messages.SIDE+ " BOOLEAN, "
                + Messages.TYPE + " TEXT )";
```

However, I keep running into this error

```
09-28 18:45:14.803  14760-14789/lltest.mohsin.com.chattest E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) near "FOREIGN": syntax error
09-28 18:45:14.807  14760-14789/lltest.mohsin.com.chattest W/System.err﹕ android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "FOREIGN": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Messages( FOREIGN KEY(RoomID) REFERENCES ChatRooms(RoomID), Message TEXT, Side BOOLEAN, Type TEXT )
09-28 18:45:14.807  14760-14789/lltest.mohsin.com.chattest W/System.err﹕ at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
09-28 18:45:14.807  14760-14789/lltest.mohsin.com.chattest W/System.err﹕ at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
09-28 18:45:14.807  14760-14789/lltest.mohsin.com.chattest W/System.err﹕ at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
09-28 18:45:14.811  14760-14789/lltest.mohsin.com.chattest W/System.err﹕ at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your `FOREIGN KEY` definition should *follow* the column definitions.

See example in SQLite Manual: https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

Once you do that, it will fail again, because the foreign key column (`RoomID`) is undefined.

Comment: So I did the following. String CREATE_TABLE_MESSAGES = "CREATE TABLE " + Messages.TABLE  + "( "
                + Messages.KEY_ROOMID  + " TEXT, "
                + Messages.MESSAGE+ " TEXT, "
                + Messages.SIDE+ " BOOLEAN, "
                + Messages.TYPE + " TEXT, "
                + "FOREIGN KEY(" + Messages.KEY_ROOMID  + ") REFERENCES "+ChatRooms.TABLE+"("+ChatRooms.KEY_ROOMID+"))";                     However, the FOREIGN key isn't working correctly because it allows me to put ids into the Messages table which don't exist in the Users tables

Comment: It seems you have not defined a `FOREIGN KEY` for the `Users` table -- only for `ChatRooms`.

Comment: Sounds like you got your table created, so that makes the end of this question. If you have a different problem, I suggest posting a new question, but you should consider phrasing it differently, because your message table doesn't have a FOREIGN KEY to a Users table.